# Why is ValidateValueCallback called twice?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

Suppose I've the following DependencyObject type,

```
public class Test : DependencyObject
{


    public int Order
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(OrderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OrderProperty",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(Test),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(6,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOrderPropertyChanged),
            new CoerceValueCallback(OnCoerceValueCallBack)),
        new ValidateValueCallback(OnValidateValueCallBack));

    static void OnOrderPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnOrderPropertyChanged");
    }

    static object OnCoerceValueCallBack(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnCoerceValueCallBack");
       return 200;
    }

    static bool OnValidateValueCallBack(object value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidateValueCallBack");
        int iValue = (int)value;
        return iValue > 5;
    }
}
```

When I create an instance of *Test*, I see `OnValidateValueCallBack` is called twice and `OnCoerceValueCallBack` isn't called at all. Based on what I saw, I guess when I create the instance, WPF will call `OnValidateValueCallBack` to check whether the default value is valid, if so, it will use the default value and won't call `CoerceValueCallback` at all, so where does the second call of `OnValidateValueCallBack` come from?

Comment: Set a break point and use stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this behavior. Upon registering a dependency property, the validate callback is called by the internals of WPF. **One call always occurs**, regardless of the metadata passed. **A second call only occurs when a default value is passed** with the metadata.

Originally I thought the first call was due to internal initialization of WPF, so it would always be the default value of the type. This is not the case! **The object passed in the first call is either the default value of the type, or the default value which is specified in the metadata**. The second call seems more logical, and just passes the default value.

No coerce or changed callbacks are called upon registering.

What the use of the first call is is a mystery to me.

[Relevant (unanswered) question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/67bc154c-9645-4c88-8e2a-5db75d171a7f) on msdn.